# How to implement queue and priority queue in Tcl?

Tags: data-structures, tcl

I have to implement either queue or priority queue in Tcl without use of any library.

I have tried to write below code. Kindly help me to implement queue in better way in Tcl/Tk.

**create node**

```
// crearting node element of queue  

proc createNode {name cost} {
            namespace eval $name [subst {     
                variable cost $cost  
                variable this $name   
            }]
```

**functions**

```
proc ${name}::getCost {} {  
            variable cost  
            return $cost  
        }  
      return $name  
     }
```

**delete queue**

```
 proc deQueue name {  
           #upvar 1 $name queue  
           set queue $name  
           set res [lindex $queue 0]  
           set queue [lrange $queue 1 end]; # remove the first element  
           set res; # return the value  
        }
```

**queue insertion**

```
  proc enQueue {newNode name} { 
            #upvar 1 $name queue  
            set queue $name  
            set queue [concat $newNode $queue]  
        }
```

**create queue**

```
 proc makeQueue {n g } {   
            set queue [list [createNode $n $g ]] 
            return $queue   
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple queue implementation:

```
proc enqueue {name item} {
    upvar 1 $name queue
    lappend queue $item
}

proc dequeue name {
    upvar 1 $name queue
    set queue [lassign $queue item]
    return $item
}

% enqueue a foo
% set item [dequeue a]
```

A simple priority queue:

```
proc enpqueue {name prio item} {
    upvar 1 $name queue
    lappend queue [list $prio $item]
    set queue [lsort -decreasing -integer -index 0 $queue]
}

proc depqueue name {
    upvar 1 $name queue
    set queue [lassign $queue prioitem]
    return [lindex $prioitem 1]
}

% enpqueue a 10 foo
% enpqueue a 40 bar
% set item [depqueue a]
bar
```

The only thing you need for a queue or priority queue is a list and an add/remove interface.

If you want to store structured data in the queue, make the `item` either a tuple of data:

```
set item [list "Smith, John" 42 1500]
```

or a dictionary:

```
set item [list name "Smith, John" age 42 foo 1500]
```

Documentation:
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: You might want to look at [struct::prioqueue](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/prioqueue.html "Create and manipulate prioqueue objects") and
[struct::queue](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/queue.html "Create and manipulate queue objects") in the Tcllib.

Comment: Sir, As in create node section of my question. I want to create a node and want to enqueue or dequeue this node in the queue. Could u plz suggest me there?

Comment: @Avi: it hard to tell what you intend to do. It seems like you are creating a rudimentary OOP system and put instances in the queue, but for the purposes you have mentioned here, you don't need objects.

Comment: Sir, I want to implement queue using linked list in which node of linked list has multiple fields (like structure)

Comment: @Avi: I added a couple of examples of storing structured data. Do you want the priority queue to prioritize over data in the structure?

Comment: Thank you, I got my answer. No,  I can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Queues are abstract data structures with two (key) operations: `add` and `get` (and an `empty` test is pretty common too). They're sufficiently complex internally that it's probably best to think in terms of using a TclOO object as their implementation:

```
oo::class create Queue {
    variable q
    constructor {} {
        set q {}
    }
    method add {item} {
        lappend q $item
        return
    }
    method empty {} {
        expr {[llength $q] == 0}
    }
    method get {} {
        if {[my empty]} {
            return -code error "queue is empty"
        }
        set q [lassign $q item]
        return $item
    }
}
```

Priority queues are like queues, except that they have a priority as well and sort by that priority. The trick to implementing them efficiently is *not* to sort on each `add` or `get`, but rather to only sort when necessary. (Or you can use an appropriate balanced tree, but they're quite complicated.)

```
oo::class create PriorityQueue {
    variable q sorted
    constructor {} {
        set q {}
        set sorted 1
    }
    method add {item priority} {
        lappend q $item $priority
        set sorted 0
        return
    }
    method empty {} {
        expr {[llength $q] == 0}
    }
    method get {} {
        if {[my empty]} {
            return -code error "queue is empty"
        }
        if {!$sorted} {
            # You might want other options here, depending on what "priority" means
            set q [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -integer $q]
            set sorted 1
        }
        set q [lassign $q item priority]
        return $item
    }
}
```

Using these data structures is fairly simple:

```
# Instantiate
set myq [PriorityQueue new]
# Add some values
$myq add "The quick brown fox" 12
$myq add "The lazy dog" 34
# Drain the queue
while {![$myq empty]} {
    puts [$myq get]
}
# Get rid of it now we're done
$myq destroy
```

Comment: Working out how to use the ordinary queue is left as an exercise to the reader…

Comment: Note that the `-stride` option of `lsort` is in Tcl 8.6, not in older versions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can u suggest me here, I want to add items in queue which has multiple fields(structure). Like creating queue using linked list.  For example node has fields int type A , string type S , flot type F etc. I want to add this node in Queue / Pq.

Comment: The items themselves can be as complicated as you want. Put a dictionary in if you need to express complexity; the queue/prioqueue will continue working as it just treats each item as an unexamined payload.

Comment: Thank you ,  it is very helpful .

Comment: I just used this PriorityQueue to complete Day 14 Part2 of Advent of Code 2021.  Very useful